# Recursive Python function returning PowerSet of items

Tags: python, recursion, nested-lists

I'm trying to debug a program and am running into issues. Can anybody direct me to the issue here?

The program is meant to take a list of items, and returns the list of powersets for those items.

An example:

```
>>> getAllSubsets([1,2])
[[1,2],[1],[2],[]]
```

The code:

```
def getAllSubsets(lst):
    if not lst:
        return []
    withFirst = [ [lst[0]] + rest for rest in getAllSubsets(lst[1:]) ]
    withoutFirst = getAllSubsets(lst[1:])
    return withFirst + withoutFirst
```

Comment: What issues are you running into? Also, you don't have to call `getAllSubsets` twice; call it once and save the result.

Comment: What are the issues?

Comment: It just keeps recursing until it returns empty lists all the way back up again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are better recipes, yes. But I think the problem with your code is that you should replace `return []` with `return [[]]`. The empty set is itself a subset.

Answer (score 2):

There's a `powerset` generator in [the recipes section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) of [the itertools documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html); you should use that.

```
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

Answer (score -1):

I found this solution on the internet:

```
def powset3(seq):
    if seq:
        p = powset3(seq[1:])
        return p + [x + seq[:1] for x in p]
    else:
        return [[]]
```