# NgramCollocationFinder in NLTK

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, nltk

I have a list of ngram terms and I want to use the tests present in the NLTK toolkit to rank the terms. But in NLTK.collocations there are only BigramCollocationFinder, TrigramCollocationFinder, QuadgramCollocationFinder. What can I do if I have a 5gram, 6gram in the terms list?

Comment: You need to take the QuadgramCollocationFinder, and extend it. Possibly generalising to allow for the NGramCollocationFinder. Which sound like a task possibly helped by a [powerset recipe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32407014/1548472)...

Comment: Somewhat related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/33021916/1548472, which is the same question for `n=5`

Answer (score 2):

In order to realise an `NGramCollocationFinder` you need to get rid of the multiude of `i`&`x` variables. To get rid of them you need to see that the pattern used are all combinations of a list of `n` items. The next step is to replace the variables with a dictionary using this combination as keys.

Finally you need to build some logic to update each combination based upon the given `w#` variables if an index is present in the combination set.  It can be done, but I suggest doing it for `n=3` or `n=4` for starters, where you can verify the logic in existing classes. When these are correct, you can use it for larger `n`'s.

### Finding the combinations

There is a `powerset()` generator in [the recipes section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) of [the itertools documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) which you can use to realise the combinations<sup>1</sup>.

```
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

Here the `(1,2)` tuple corresponds to the `iix` variable, and the `(1,3)` tuple corresponds to the `ixi` variable. So based on the tuple length, and the presence of the different indexes it is possible to replace all the `i`&`x` variables.

### Do tuple logic

Another tool you need to achieve your goal, is to be able to add to tuples. This is needed to extend/replace the arguments within `score_ngram()`. Here is a really simple example on how to add to a tuple:

```
a = (1, 2)
b = a + (3, )    # Notice the trailing comma to make it one element tuple
# b is now (1, 2, 3)
```

The rest, as they say, is left for you to implement. For some help on sections you need to analyze see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33025730/1548472) on the related question: "[Transform QuadgramCollationFinder into PentagramCollationFinder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33021916/1548472)".

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Thanks to [Cyphase](https://stackoverflow.com/users/892383/cyphase) describing this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32407014/1548472)</sub>