# Transform QuadgramCollationFinder into PentagramCollationFinder

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, nltk

I tried to transform the QuadgramCollationFinde class present in NLTK toolkit into a `PentagramCollocationFinder one`, that is to use 5 items, not only 4 item, but is does work.

this is the nltk classe

```
import nltk
from nltk.compat import iteritems
from nltk.probability import FreqDist
from nltk.util import ngrams
from nltk.metrics import ContingencyMeasures, BigramAssocMeasures,TrigramAssocMeasures
from nltk.metrics.spearman import ranks_from_scores, spearman_correlation
from __future__ import print_function

class QuadgramCollocationFinder(AbstractCollocationFinder):
    """A tool for the finding and ranking of quadgram collocations or other association measures.
    It is often useful to use from_words() rather than constructing an instance directly.
    """
    default_ws = 4

    def __init__(self, word_fd, quadgram_fd, ii, iii, ixi, ixxi, iixi, ixii):
        """Construct a QuadgramCollocationFinder, given FreqDists for appearances of words,
        bigrams, trigrams, two words with one word and two words between them, three words
        with a word between them in both variations.
        """
        AbstractCollocationFinder.__init__(self, word_fd, quadgram_fd)
        self.iii = iii
        self.ii = ii
        self.ixi = ixi
        self.ixxi = ixxi
        self.iixi = iixi
        self.ixii = ixii


    def from_words(cls, words, window_size=4):
        if window_size < 4:
            raise ValueError("Specify window_size at least 4")
        ixxx = FreqDist()
        iiii = FreqDist()
        ii = FreqDist()
        iii = FreqDist()
        ixi = FreqDist()
        ixxi = FreqDist()
        iixi = FreqDist()
        ixii = FreqDist()

        for window in ngrams(words, window_size, pad_right=True):
            w1 = window[0]
            if w1 is None: 
                continue
            for w2, w3, w4 in _itertools.combinations(window[1:], 3):
                ixxx[w1] += 1
                if w2 is None:
                    continue
                ii[(w1, w2)] += 1
                if w3 is None:
                    continue
                iii[(w1, w2, w3)] += 1
                ixi[(w1, w3)] += 1
                if w4 is None:
                    continue
                iiii[(w1, w2, w3, w4)] += 1
                ixxi[(w1, w4)] += 1
                ixii[(w1, w3, w4)] += 1
                iixi[(w1, w2, w4)] += 1

        return cls(ixxx, iiii, ii, iii, ixi, ixxi, iixi, ixii)


    def score_ngram(self, score_fn, w1, w2, w3, w4):
        n_all = self.word_fd.N()
        n_iiii = self.ngram_fd[(w1, w2, w3, w4)]
        if not n_iiii:
            return
        n_iiix = self.iii[(w1, w2, w3)]
        n_xiii = self.iii[(w2, w3, w4)]
        n_iixi = self.iixi[(w1, w2, w4)]
        n_ixii = self.ixii[(w1, w3, w4)]

        n_iixx = self.ii[(w1, w2)]
        n_xxii = self.ii[(w3, w4)]
        n_xiix = self.ii[(w2, w3)]
        n_ixix = self.ixi[(w1, w3)]
        n_ixxi = self.ixxi[(w1, w4)]
        n_xixi = self.ixi[(w2, w4)]

        n_ixxx = self.word_fd[w1]
        n_xixx = self.word_fd[w2]
        n_xxix = self.word_fd[w3]
        n_xxxi = self.word_fd[w4]
        return score_fn(n_iiii,
                        (n_iiix, n_iixi, n_ixii, n_xiii),
                        (n_iixx, n_ixix, n_ixxi, n_xixi, n_xxii, n_xiix),
                        (n_ixxx, n_xixx, n_xxix, n_xxxi),
                        n_all)
```

This is what I treid

```
class fivegramCollocationFinder(AbstractCollocationFinder):
"""A tool for the finding and ranking of quadgram collocations or other association measures.
It is often useful to use from_words() rather than constructing an instance directly.
"""
default_ws = 4

def __init__(self, word_fd, quingram_fd, ii, iii, ixi,iiii,ixxi, ixii, iixi, ixxxi, iixxi, ixixi, ixxii, iiixi, ixiii, iixii):
    """Construct a QuadgramCollocationFinder, given FreqDists for appearances of words,
    bigrams, trigrams, two words with one word and two words between them, three words
    with a word between them in both variations.
    """
    AbstractCollocationFinder.__init__(self, word_fd, quingram_fd)
    self.iiii = iiii
    self.iii = iii
    self.ii = ii
    self.ixi = ixi
    self.ixxi = ixxi
    self.iixi = iixi
    self.ixii = ixii
    self.ixxxi = ixxxi
    self.iixxi = iixxi
    self.ixixi = ixixi
    self.ixxii = ixxii
    self.iiixi = iiixi
    self.ixiii = ixiii
    self.iixii = iixii

@classmethod

def from_words(cls, words, window_size=5):
    if window_size < 5:
        raise ValueError("Specify window_size at least 4")
    ixxxx = FreqDist()
    ii =  FreqDist()
    iii = FreqDist()
    iiii = FreqDist()
    iiiii = FreqDist()
    ixi = FreqDist()
    ixxi = FreqDist()
    iixi = FreqDist()
    ixii = FreqDist()
    ixxxi = FreqDist()
    iixxi  = FreqDist()
    ixixi  = FreqDist()
    ixxii = FreqDist()
    iiixi = FreqDist()
    ixiii = FreqDist()
    iixii   = FreqDist()


    for window in ngrams(words, window_size, pad_right=True):
        w1 = window[0]
        if w1 is None: 
            continue
        for w2, w3, w4, w5 in _itertools.combinations(window[1:], 4):
            ixxxx[w1] += 1
            if w2 is None:
                continue
            ii[(w1, w2)] += 1
            if w3 is None:
                continue
            iii[(w1, w2, w3)] += 1
            ixi[(w1, w3)] += 1
            if w4 is None:
                continue
            iiii[(w1, w2, w3, w4)] += 1
            ixxi[(w1, w4)] += 1
            ixii[(w1, w3, w4)] += 1
            iixi[(w1, w2, w4)] += 1
            if w5 is None:
                continue
            iiiii[(w1, w2, w3, w4, w5)] += 1
            ixxxi[(w1, w5)] += 1
            iixxi[(w1, w2, w5)] += 1
            ixixi[(w1, w3, w5)] += 1
            ixxii[(w1, w4, w5)] += 1
            iiixi[(w1, w2, w3, w5)] +=1
            ixiii[(w1, w3, w4, w5)] +=1
            iixii[(w1, w2, w4, w5)] +=1


    return cls(ixxxx, ii,iii, ixi, ixxi, iixi, ixii,iiii, iiiii, ixxxi, iixxi, ixixi, ixxii, iiixi, ixiii, iixii)


def score_ngram(self, score_fn, w1, w2, w3, w4, w5):
    n_all = self.word_fd.N()
    n_iiiii = self.ngram_fd[(w1, w2, w3, w4, w5)]
    if not n_iiiii:
        return


    n_iiixi = self.iiixi[(w1, w2, w3, w5)]
    n_ixiii = self.ixiii[(w1, w3, w4, w5)]
    n_iixii = self.iixii[(w1, w2, w4, w5)]
    n_iiiix = self.iiii[(w1,w2,w3,w4)]
    n_xiiii = self.iiii[(w2,w3,w4,w5)]

    n_iixix = self.iixix[(w1, w2, w4)]
    n_iixxi = self.iixxi[(w1, w2, w5)]
    n_ixixi = self.ixixi[(w1, w3, w5)]
    n_ixxii = self.ixxii[(w1, w4, w5)]
    n_xiixi = self.xiixi[(w2, w3, w5)]
    n_xixii = self.xixii[(w2, w4, w5)]
    n_ixiix = self.ixiix[(w1, w3, w4)]
    n_iiixx = self.iii[(w1, w2, w3)]
    n_xiiix = self.iii[(w2, w3, w4)]
    n_xxiii = self.iii[(w3, w4, w5)]




    n_ixixx = self.ixixx[(w1, w3)]
    n_ixxix = self.ixxix[(w1, w4)]
    n_ixxxi = self.ixxxi[(w1, w5)]
    n_xixix = self.xixix[(w2, w4)]
    n_xixxi = self.xixxi[(w2, w5)]
    n_xxixi = self.xxixi[(w2, w5)]
    n_iixxx = self.ii[(w1, w2)]
    n_xiixx = self.ii[(w2, w3)]
    n_xxiix= self.ii[(w3, w4)]
    n_xxxii= self.ii[(w4, w5)]


    n_ixxxx = self.word_fd[w1]
    n_xixxx = self.word_fd[w2]
    n_xxixx = self.word_fd[w3]
    n_xxxix = self.word_fd[w4]
    n_xxxxi = self.word_fd[w5]

    return score_fn(n_iiiii,
                    (n_iiixi, n_ixiii, n_iixii, n_iiiix, n_xiiii), 
                    (n_iixix,n_iixxi, n_ixixi, n_ixxii, n_xiixi, n_xixii,n_ixiix, n_iiixx, n_xiiix, n_xxiii),
                    (n_ixixx, n_ixxix,n_ixxxi, n_xixix, n_xixxi, n_xxixi, n_iixxx, n_xiixx,n_xxiix,n_xxxii),
                    (n_ixxxx,n_xixxx, n_xxixx, n_xxxix, n_xxxxi),
                    n_all)
```

So what is needed is to update the class to detect also `PentagramCollocationFinder`

Can someone help?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be any magic to it, you just need to buckle up, and do the hard work. Or do you expect the community to do your work for you? Or is there some aspect of it, you don't know how to expand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building the patterns seems to be of some concern, so here is some code which builds all legal i-patterns, and n-patterns to be used.

```
import collections

def make_ngram_ipatterns(n):
    """Make all needed patterns used by *gramCollocationFinder up to n words"""

    i_patterns = []

    for i in xrange(1, n+1):
        if i <= 2:
            i_patterns.append('i' * i)

        else:
            for j in xrange(2**(i-2)):
                 bin_str = '{0:0{1}b}'.format(j, i-2)
                 ix_pattern = bin_str.replace('0', 'x').replace('1', 'i')
                 i_patterns.append('i{}i'.format(ix_pattern))

    return i_patterns

def make_ngram_npatterns(n):
    """Make all needed n-patterings used by *gramCollocationFinder up to n words"""
    all_ipatterns = make_ngram_ipatterns(n)

    npatterns = []

    for ipattern in all_ipatterns:
         i_order = sum(c == 'i' for c in ipattern)
         i_length = len(ipattern)
         for j in xrange(n - i_length+1):
             npattern = 'n_{}{}{}'.format('x'* j,
                                           ipattern ,
                                           'x'* (n - i_length - j))

             npatterns.append((i_order, ipattern, npattern))

    return sorted(npatterns)


def main():

    n = 5

    all_ipatterns = make_ngram_ipatterns(n)

    print '\n'.join(make_ngram_ipatterns(n))

    for order, ipattern, npattern in make_ngram_npatterns(n):
         wparams = ', '.join('w{}'.format(i+1)
                                for i, c in enumerate(npattern[2:])
                                if c == 'i'
                            )
         print('order: {1:2}   ipattern: {2:{0}s}   npattern: {3}'
               ' ->  {3} = self.{2}({4})'.format(
                   n, order, ipattern, npattern, wparams))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output for `n=5` as it stands are:

```
i
ii
ixi
iii
ixxi
ixii
iixi
iiii
ixxxi
ixxii
ixixi
ixiii
iixxi
iixii
iiixi
iiiii
order:  1   ipattern: i       npattern: n_ixxxx ->  n_ixxxx = self.i(w1)
order:  1   ipattern: i       npattern: n_xixxx ->  n_xixxx = self.i(w2)
order:  1   ipattern: i       npattern: n_xxixx ->  n_xxixx = self.i(w3)
order:  1   ipattern: i       npattern: n_xxxix ->  n_xxxix = self.i(w4)
order:  1   ipattern: i       npattern: n_xxxxi ->  n_xxxxi = self.i(w5)
order:  2   ipattern: ii      npattern: n_iixxx ->  n_iixxx = self.ii(w1, w2)
order:  2   ipattern: ii      npattern: n_xiixx ->  n_xiixx = self.ii(w2, w3)
order:  2   ipattern: ii      npattern: n_xxiix ->  n_xxiix = self.ii(w3, w4)
order:  2   ipattern: ii      npattern: n_xxxii ->  n_xxxii = self.ii(w4, w5)
order:  2   ipattern: ixi     npattern: n_ixixx ->  n_ixixx = self.ixi(w1, w3)
order:  2   ipattern: ixi     npattern: n_xixix ->  n_xixix = self.ixi(w2, w4)
order:  2   ipattern: ixi     npattern: n_xxixi ->  n_xxixi = self.ixi(w3, w5)
order:  2   ipattern: ixxi    npattern: n_ixxix ->  n_ixxix = self.ixxi(w1, w4)
order:  2   ipattern: ixxi    npattern: n_xixxi ->  n_xixxi = self.ixxi(w2, w5)
order:  2   ipattern: ixxxi   npattern: n_ixxxi ->  n_ixxxi = self.ixxxi(w1, w5)
order:  3   ipattern: iii     npattern: n_iiixx ->  n_iiixx = self.iii(w1, w2, w3)
order:  3   ipattern: iii     npattern: n_xiiix ->  n_xiiix = self.iii(w2, w3, w4)
order:  3   ipattern: iii     npattern: n_xxiii ->  n_xxiii = self.iii(w3, w4, w5)
order:  3   ipattern: iixi    npattern: n_iixix ->  n_iixix = self.iixi(w1, w2, w4)
order:  3   ipattern: iixi    npattern: n_xiixi ->  n_xiixi = self.iixi(w2, w3, w5)
order:  3   ipattern: iixxi   npattern: n_iixxi ->  n_iixxi = self.iixxi(w1, w2, w5)
order:  3   ipattern: ixii    npattern: n_ixiix ->  n_ixiix = self.ixii(w1, w3, w4)
order:  3   ipattern: ixii    npattern: n_xixii ->  n_xixii = self.ixii(w2, w4, w5)
order:  3   ipattern: ixixi   npattern: n_ixixi ->  n_ixixi = self.ixixi(w1, w3, w5)
order:  3   ipattern: ixxii   npattern: n_ixxii ->  n_ixxii = self.ixxii(w1, w4, w5)
order:  4   ipattern: iiii    npattern: n_iiiix ->  n_iiiix = self.iiii(w1, w2, w3, w4)
order:  4   ipattern: iiii    npattern: n_xiiii ->  n_xiiii = self.iiii(w2, w3, w4, w5)
order:  4   ipattern: iiixi   npattern: n_iiixi ->  n_iiixi = self.iiixi(w1, w2, w3, w5)
order:  4   ipattern: iixii   npattern: n_iixii ->  n_iixii = self.iixii(w1, w2, w4, w5)
order:  4   ipattern: ixiii   npattern: n_ixiii ->  n_ixiii = self.ixiii(w1, w3, w4, w5)
order:  5   ipattern: iiiii   npattern: n_iiiii ->  n_iiiii = self.iiiii(w1, w2, w3, w4, w5)
```

Changing to a new dimension is now a matter of using and setting all i-patterns as a lower order class, replacing the n-patterns, and collating all n-patterns of same order into `score_fn()` sets.

*Edit:* Completed the setting of the n-patterns with appropriate `w#`'s

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to require more than a lot of work, but you have some definitions to make. Like should you allow for more than two separation? This makes the internal logic even longer, but still doable.

Another issue is whether you want to continue going down the path of a multitude of `ixxi`, `ixii`, ... variables, or if you should collate all of these in a dictionary consisting of all permutations allowed of `n` variables?

### Plain expansion

All the four letter variable, will still be needed, but you need to add the five letter variations, that is you need to add all variations like the following into `__init__`: `ixxxi`, `iiixi`, `iixii`, ..., `iixxi`, `ixxii`. These variables also need to be added as parameter both to the class, as well as the `cls()` intialiser used in `from_words()`.

In `from_words()` you also do need both to intialise the new five letter variables, as well as add another block like for all 8 variables:

```
if w5 is None:
     continue
iiiii[(w1, w2, w3, w4, w5)] += 1
ixxxi[(w1, w5)] += 1
iiixi[(w1, w2, w3, w5)] +=
...
ixxii[(w1,w3,w4,w5)= +=
```

And similarily you need to add these 8 five letter variables to `score_ngram()`. Notice how all these start and end with `i`.

You need of course also to change all 4's to 5, add `w5` in appropriate places, and so on.

The last change you need to make is to add corresponding lines to `score_ngram()` where you also need to add cases to the lower order `n_iixx` & co. And a line to the `score_fn()` call for four known `i`'s.

Regarding the `n_####` combinations, you need to extend them to be `n_#####` combinations, and add all related permutations. The first block with three words, needs to extended to:

```
n_iiixx, n_xiiix, +n_xxiii ~ self.iii(...)
n_iixix, +n_xiixi ~ self.iixi(...)
n_ixiix, +n_xixii ~ self.ixii(...)
```

where `+` represent new variations, and the other are just modification of the corresponding block. For `n_xiixi` you add in corresponding `w#` matching the `i`'s, in other words `self.iixi[(w2, w3, w5)]`.

### Alternate expansion

You could also get rid of all the `i` and `x` variables as suggested in [my answer] on the related question: "[NgramCollocationFinder in NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33021298/ngramcollocationfinder-in-nltk#comment53872426_33021298)". But that requires even more work!

Comment: itertools.combinations(window[1:], 3) will be changed?

Comment: (ixi[(w1, w3)] += 1) will  remain?

Comment: see my trial in the edited code. Why does not it works?

Comment: so :ixixx, ixxix, xixix, iixix, ixiix should be removed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91853/discussion-between-holroy-and-user3573552).

Comment: look at it now, I made all the changes, but always does not work